# Unexpected response with Google Safe Browsing API v4 and Python requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests, safe-browsing

I'm trying to implement a small function to verify possible phishing URL's and thought that using Google Safe Browsing API would be a good start.

After reading the API documentation I thought I had a handle on things and cobbled together the following code:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key=<REDACTED>"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

payload = {'client': {'clientId': "mycompany", 'clientVersion': "0.1"},
        'threatInfo': {'threatTypes': ["SOCIAL_ENGINEERING", "MALWARE"],
                       'platformTypes': ["ANY_PLATFORM"],
                       'threatEntryTypes': ["URL"],
                       'threatEntries:': [{'url': "http://www.urltocheck1.org"}]}}

print (json.dumps(payload, indent=4))

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

If I do a

> print (json.dumps(payload, indent=4)

it all *looks* ok. However, the reply I get back from Google doesn't agree.

> {'error': {'message': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name
>   "threat_entries:" at \'threat_info\': Cannot find field.', 'status':
>   'INVALID_ARGUMENT', 'code': 400, 'details': [{'@type':
>   'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations':
>   [{'field': 'threat_info', 'description': 'Invalid JSON payload
>   received. Unknown name "threat_entries:" at \'threat_info\': Cannot
>   find field.'}]}]}} {'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
>   'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Date':
>   'Tue, 25 Oct 2016 07:55:30 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;
>   charset=UTF-8', 'Alt-Svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000;
>   v="36,35,34,33,32"', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
>   'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block',
>   'Server': 'ESF'} application/json; charset=UTF-8

I can't - as usual - spot my mistake. Can someone else spot it and possibly put me on the correct track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove unnecessary colon after `threatEntries`
and it should work just fine.

Also if you are using `requests` version 2.4.2 or newer you do not need to insert `content-type` header to your code, instead you could move your key to the `params` section:

```
import requests
import json

api_key='your_key'
url = "https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find"
payload = {'client': {'clientId': "mycompany", 'clientVersion': "0.1"},
        'threatInfo': {'threatTypes': ["SOCIAL_ENGINEERING", "MALWARE"],
                       'platformTypes': ["ANY_PLATFORM"],
                       'threatEntryTypes': ["URL"],
                       'threatEntries': [{'url': "http://www.urltocheck1.org"}]}}
params = {'key': api_key}
r = requests.post(url, params=params, json=payload)
# Print response
print(r) 
print(r.json())
```